# Linq query fails if include query has takelast limiter

Tags: c#, linq, query-string

I would like to use this query, so I won't get all child rows, but the last 10.

```
var list = await _context.Parent
                .Include(gs => gs.Child
                                    .OrderBy(gsm => gsm.Time)
                                    .TakeLast(10))
                .ToListAsync();
```

After the try catch turning off following error message appears:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression
> 'gs.GreenSpeedMess.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(gsm =>
> gsm.MesTime).TakeLast(10)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To
> target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by
> composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take
> operations. For more information on including related data, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

How do I have to set up my query string to get just the last child row?

Comment: Does it do the same if you OrderByDescendibg and Take. And when you say "just the last" you mean you want a single row? Also, is it an n-per-group or an n-per-query you're looking for?

Comment: Just tried and yes it does.
I want for every parent row, just the last child row

Comment: Does it still if you remove the order/take entirely?

Comment: *and continues* - what does this mean? I've never seen code continue on after an uncaught exception

Comment: I edited my question. Should be more clear now

Comment: Can't reproduce this with EF5: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgn9c.png - EF forms the query how I'd expect, namely that a ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY... ) is used to provide a row numbering per customer, whereupon the Take is a where rownumber< x. Post a full code that reproduces, including the entity definitions, db context setup, and confirm the EF version in use

Comment: Close the Include method first, *then* do order by (etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how the `Include` method works. As implied by the example in the exception message, the expected return value of the passed predicate is a navigation property of the original object.
Its use is simply to define which navigation properties should be loaded in the query results.

In your example you'd first want to define that the child navigation should be loaded:

```
var list = await _context.Parent
                .Include(parent => parent.Child)
                .ToListAsync();
```

And on a second step you'd then want to do the operation:

```
list.ForEach(parent => parent.Child
                       .OrderBy(gsm => gsm.Time)
                       .TakeLast(10));
```

More information on the `Include` method can be found at the microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-5.0